# updating matrix elements based on a condition

Tags: matrix, binary, finite-fields

I am (still) fairly new to Mathematica and trying to perform some operation on the matrix elements, say for the matrix

```
mat= {{0,0,0,1,2,3,1,3,0,2},{1,0,0,3,2,3,1,2,0,0},{0,1,0,1,0,3,1,2,3,2}}
```

and want to perform  this map `0->00,1->01,2->10,3->11`. (to give more context to it I want to convert the matrix mat in [GF(4)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteField.html) to binary). It might seem straightforward but I am being unable to do this matrix operations (I tried the Replace or ReplacePart operations). Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `mat = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 
    0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2}} /. {0 -> "00", 1 -> "01",  
   2 -> "10", 3 -> "11"}` or `BaseForm[mat, 2]`

Comment: Of course, `00` is interpreted as `0` unless you are working with strings.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, if I want to obtain the resulting matrix after the mapping in the regular form like `{{0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0}, {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0}}` should I use some kind partitioning/ flatten-unflatten command? (I already tried with some of them)

Comment: @march. Yes, please-it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @reach2brb. See updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some options for the example matrix

```
mat = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 0, 2}
       , {1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0}
       , {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2}};
```

---

The following returns a list at each spot with the binary digits as elements:

```
list = Map[IntegerDigits[#, 2, 2] &, mat, {2}]
(* {{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}}
      , {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}
      , {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}} *)
```

To invert this, do

```
Map[FromDigits[#, 2] &, list, {2}]
```

---

This one takes the previous and combines the digits into a string:

```
list = Map[StringJoin @@ ToString /@ IntegerDigits[#, 2, 2] &, mat, {2}]
(* {{"00", "00", "00", "01", "10", "11", "01", "11", "00", "10"}
     , {"01", "00", "00", "11", "10", "11", "01", "10", "00", "00"}
     , {"00", "01", "00", "01",  "00", "11", "01", "10", "11", "10"}} *)
```

To invert this, do

```
Map[FromDigits[ToExpression /@ Characters[#], 2] &, list, {2}]
```

---

This one writes it in base form explicitly:

```
list = Map[BaseForm[#, 2] &, mat, {2}]
```

but it doesn't give both digits and it's purely for display purposes. To invert that do

```
list /. BaseForm[a_, _] :> a
```